# Set the path to the global configuration file in cordova?

Tags: cordova, config

I'm trying to run my cordova project.
What do I really want?
I want to set the path to the `config.xml` via command prompt.
I tried to do smth like this:

`$ cordova run ios --target='iPhone-6' --buildConfig=./app/config.dist.xml`

but it says me that

`Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.`
If I create `config.xml` in current working directory and run the project without any arguments everything is fine.
So, is it possible to have config file in another folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/), config.xml can either exist in project root folder or `project_ root/www` folder.

Also the naming convention of the file should be `config.xml` in order to build the same using  Cordova CLI as far as I know. Moreover, `cordova create` command sets up the basic project structure for you including config.xml. Its advisable to stick to this structure rather than customizing the locations to avoid errors.

Comment: @user3818229 Glad it helped.Happy coding. Cheers:)

Comment: Dint understand why the answer is down-voted even when the questioner himself has accepted the answer. Really terrible.